# Android View onHover not firing

Tags: android, onhover

I have the most simple of applications where I would expect to be receiving hover events and unfortunately, no matter what I try, I cannot seem to be able to receive them.  I can guess that something somewhere else is receiving them and consuming them yet there are only two views in the layout, a RelativeLayout container and the TextView.  Changing the RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout has no positive impact, nor does calling setOnHoverListener on the TextView instance.

My application is targeted for 4.0.3 (API 15).  The source is near identical to the hover example provided in the SDK sources.  It *should* just work.  I've seen it work in the past.

If someone can shed any light on what I may not be seeing or have any advice of things that I can look at, it would be much appreciated.

Hardware: *Sony Xperia Sola*

Android version: *4.0.4*

*Activity source:*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView mMessageTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMessageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        View container = findViewById(R.id.container);
        container.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
                        mMessageTextView.setText("Entered: " + event.getX() + ":" + event.getY());
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE:
                        mMessageTextView.setText("Move: " + event.getX() + ":" + event.getY());
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
                        mMessageTextView.setText("Exit: " + event.getX() + ":" + event.getY());
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look to the linked example, maybe it will useful to you: http://www.vogella.com/code/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProviderActivity.html

Comment: @JeremyD container is certainly not null, otherwise a npe would be thrown.

What I did this morning was to try a different phone (I have two of the Xperia Sola).  The test application above works.  The difference is that the one that I was working on where the application did not work was rooted.  The second Sola was not rooted.  That is the only difference between the two that I am aware of.

I would still like to know why this does not working on a rooted Xperia Sola.

Comment: @rosco Not helpful in this particular situation as it is far too involved for testing and diagnosis purposes.

Comment: Could u please paste your xml code??

Comment: I am trying to do the same on android emulator, but onhover event is never called ? I tried the ApiDemos of Android Samples but in that also this event is not being fired.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but anyway. I believe that happened to you, because some of child views would intercept hover state from parent.

Other reason may be that you didn't declare your container as focusable